# Pandas: Parsing and updating string in column with nulls

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of email addresses with some rows as null. I will be inserting this dataframe into an html email using df.to_html(), but I don't wan't the email addresses to hyperlink (other columns will have hyperlinks). The only thing I can work out, is to modify the text in the column per a suggestion on another forum to: myemail < span > @ < /span > domain.com

How can I go through and modify the values in the column (if it is not null), to parse our the email address and insert the  tags in?

Comment: `df['your_column'] = df['your_column'].str.replace('@', '<span>@</span>')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your email field is named 'mail', Like this:

```
df['mail'] = df.apply(lambda row: '<span>@</span>'.join(row['mail'].split('@')), axis=1)
```

This will modify your email field to contain the `span` tags.

Comment: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found

Comment: If you have null values in the mail column you would need to unselect all of them: e.g. `df[~df.mail.isnull()].apply(....)`

Comment: `df['mail'] = df[~df.mail.isnull()].apply(lambda row: ''.join((row['mail'].split('@')), axis=1)`  
works perfectly for this. I did change my approach since < span > wasn't working for every email client. I now use this but use the same method Rocky Li suggests:
    `<a href="No Link" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">myemail@domain.com</a>`

Comment: In case anyone wants to use it, Rocky Li's method updated with me switching my hyperlink breaking method.
`df['mail'] = df[~df.mail.isnull()].apply(lambda row: ''.join(("""<a href="No Link" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">""",row['mail'],"""</a>""")), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 >>> a = ["hello@gmail.com","hy@gmail.com"]
 >>> b = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=["Email"])
 >>> b
 Out[14]: 
         Email
  0  hello@gmail.com
  1     hy@gmail.com
>>> b["Email"] = b["Email"].str.replace("@","<span>@</span>")
>>> b
 Out[15]: 
  0    hello<span>@</span>gmail.com
  1       hy<span>@</span>gmail.com
Name: Email, dtype: object
>>> b.to_html("index.html")
```